Daniel Litt ball and urn problem - applying Bayes' Theorem
I want to use Bayes' theorem to solve the following ball and urn problem of Daniel Litt.

You are given an urn containing 100 balls; n of them are red, and
100-n are green, where n is chosen uniformly at random in [0, 100].
You take a random ball out of the urn—it’s red—and discard it. What is
the probability that the next ball you pick (out of the 99 remaining)
is red?

Let $A$ be the event where the number of red balls outnumber the green balls in the initial configuration of 100 balls. Let $B$ be the event where the first drawn ball is red. By Bayes theorem, we have
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
I am not entirely sure how to work out the three terms on the right hand side. My attempt is as follows:
$$P(B|A) = \left(1\cdot\frac{1}{100} + 0.99\cdot\frac{1}{100} + ... + 0.51\cdot\frac{1}{100}\right)$$
This is because we consider the event of there being 100 red balls and 0 green balls, 99 red balls and 1 green ball, etc. all the way down to 51 red balls and 49 green balls. Each event occurs with probability $\frac{1}{100}$. Then, the probability of drawing a red ball is $1, 0.99 ... 0.51$ respectively given each of those configurations. Next, we have
$$P(A) = 0.5 $$
This is by symmetry between red and green. Finally,
$$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^c)P(A^c)$$
Again, the last term is easily computed using $P(A^c) = 0.5$ and
$$P(B|A^c) = \left(0.5\cdot\frac{1}{100} + 0.49\cdot\frac{1}{100} + ... + 0.01\cdot\frac{1}{100}\right)$$
Putting these together, I obtain $P(A|B) = 3/4$.

Is this correct for the events $A$ and $B$.
From here, how does one compute the probability of drawing red for the next ball? The answer is supposed to be $2/3$


Removing probability-theory as I think this question does not fit that category. OP, please restore the tag if you read the tag description and believe it does in fact fit.

It seems you're doing much more work than you need to. I'm going to define a fresh set of events which simplified the calculation quite a bit.
We're going to consider the following set of events:
$E_i \rightarrow$ Urn has $i$ red balls, where $i \sim \textrm{Unif}[0, 100]$
$A \rightarrow$ First ball chosen is red.
$B \rightarrow$ Second ball chosen is red
We're interested in finding $P(B|A)$. By Bayes Theorem,
$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$
Now,
$P(A) = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{100}P(A \cap E_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}P(E_i)P(A|E_i)$
$P(E_i) = \frac{1}{101}$, and $P(A|E_i) = \frac{i}{100}$
$\therefore P(A) = \frac{1}{101*100} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{100}i = \frac{1}{2}$
Similarly, $P(B \cap A) = \bigcap\limits_{i=2}^{100}P(E_i)P(A|E_i)P(B|A \cap E_i)$.
Note that here $i$ ranges from 2 to 100 because for $i=1$, $P(B|A \cap E_1) = 0$
$P(B|A \cap E_i) = \frac{i-1}{99}$
$\therefore P(B \cap A) = \frac{1}{101*100*99} \sum\limits_{i=2}^{100}(i(i-1))$
The sum on the inside can be simplified using the identities for sum of first n naturals and sum of squares of first n naturals. Pretty much everything cancels out, leaving you with $P(B \cap A) = \frac{1}{3}$
$\therefore P(B|A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}$

Just to point out:  It's $\frac 23$ regardless of the number of balls.  That is to say, there is nothing special about the $100$.
To see this, suppose there were $K>1
$ balls in the urn.  Imagine that we had $(K+1)$ urns, one with no red balls, one with exactly one red, etc.  There would then be $K(K+1)$ balls in total, half of each color.  Further suppose that each red ball was numbered separately, as $r_{n,i}$ where the $n$ refers to the number of red balls in the relevant urn and the $i\in \{1, \cdots, n\}$ is the dummy index of the chosen ball within its urn. Now you choose an urn uniformly at random and select a ball from it uniformly at random and observe that it is red.  Each red ball is equally likely to be chosen, with probability $\frac 2{K(K+1)}$.
If you have chosen $r_{n,i}$ the probability that the next choice is also red is $\frac {n-1}{K-1}$ so the probability you want is $$\frac 2{K(K+1)}\times \sum_{n=1}^K\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {n-1}{K-1}=\frac 2{K(K+1)(K-1)}\times \sum_{n=1}^Kn(n-1)=\frac 23$$
